# cline not working in lightgray rows

Tags: tables

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}    Week & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
        
        & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        1 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
        
        \rowcolor{lightgray}    & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        \rowcolor{lightgray} 2 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        \rowcolor{lightgray}     & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is the image of what I get when I compile:

[image: Compiled table]

As you can see, the horizontal clines are not visible between the lightgray rows.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Some of the vertical lines seem not to work also. Pretty weird.

Comment: `\rowcolor` comes from `colortbl` which explicitly documents that `\cline` does not work with that package (it uses negative spacing so ends up behind the colour)

Comment: @SebGlav this is documented behaviour

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible solution via `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{lightgray}{1,5,6,7}
    \Body
    \hline
    Week & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
         & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
       1 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
         & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
         & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
       2 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
         & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `hhline` for that:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray} Week & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline

        & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        1 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline

        \rowcolor{lightgray} & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\[-0.5pt] \hhline{|~|----}
        \rowcolor{lightgray} 2 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\[-0.5pt] \hhline{|~|----}
        \rowcolor{lightgray} & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}[colortbl-like]
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}    Week & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
        & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        1 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}    & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        \rowcolor{lightgray} 2 & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \cline{2-5}
        \rowcolor{lightgray}     & Date & Topic & Pages & HW\\ \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with my new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={|c|c|c|c|c|},
      row{1,5-7}={lightgray},
      cell{2,5}{1} = {r=3}{m}, % multirow
      hlines, vlines, % hlines can not cross multirow cells
    }
      Week & Date & Topic & Pages & HW \\
      1    & Date & Topic & Pages & HW \\
           & Date & Topic & Pages & HW \\
           & Date & Topic & Pages & HW \\
      2    & Date & Topic & Pages & HW \\
           & Date & Topic & Pages & HW \\
           & Date & Topic & Pages & HW \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]